# How to find rows that has values that exists with criteria 'a' in a table but does not exist with criteria 'b'?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have an *aggregated table* like:

```
No     Field1   Type
12     -1       FR2 
12     45       FR1 
11     -1       FR2 
11     30       FR2
11     20       FR1
```

Is it possible to select *Nos* according to types where they possess negative values in Field1 and no other entries with positive values?

Is it possible to find the negation of that selection?

Hence the output should be:

```
No
11
```

**Explanation:**

I am trying to check for people who have failed a list of tests and have not retaken and passed them. Those who never failed as well as those who retook and passed is the result.

In the result output, 12 is not returned because it has negative values for FR2 and no subsequent positive values for FR2.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT No
FROM
  ( SELECT No, MAX(Field1) AS MaxField1
    FROM tableX
    GROUP BY No, Type
  ) AS tmp
GROUP BY No
HAVING MIN(MaxField1) > 0 ;
```

Tested at **[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f2ed5/3)**

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct No from yourtable
group by No,Type
having max(Field1) >0
and min(Field1)<0
```